# Неправильный Consumer

Tags: java, consumer

Дано на текущий момент 3 класса и интерфейс

```
public interface Sendable<T> {
    String getTo();
    String getFrom();
    T getContent();
}
```

```
public class MailService<T>  implements Consumer<Sendable<T>> {


    Map<String, List<T>> mailBox;

    public Map<String, List<T>> getMailBox() {
        mailBox = new HashMap<String, List<T>>() {
            @Override
            public List<T> get(Object key) {
                return super.getOrDefault(key, new LinkedList<T>());
            }
        };
        return mailBox;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Sendable<T> sendable) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(sendable.getContent());
        mailBox.put(sendable.getTo(),list);
    }
}
```

```
public class MailMessage<T> implements Sendable{

    private String message;
    private String to;
    private String from;

    public MailMessage(String to, String from, String message) {
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContent() {
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!super.equals(0)) {
            return false;
        }

        final MailMessage<?> other = (MailMessage<?>) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(this.message, other.message)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), message);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Random variables
        String randomFrom = "..."; // Некоторая случайная строка. Можете выбрать ее самостоятельно.
        String randomTo = "...";  // Некоторая случайная строка. Можете выбрать ее самостоятельно.
        int randomSalary = 100;  // Некоторое случайное целое положительное число. Можете выбрать его самостоятельно.

// Создание списка из трех почтовых сообщений.
        MailMessage firstMessage = new MailMessage(
                "Robert Howard",
                "H.P. Lovecraft",
                "This \"The Shadow over Innsmouth\" story is real masterpiece, Howard!"
        );

        assert firstMessage.getFrom().equals("Robert Howard") : "Wrong firstMessage from address";
        assert firstMessage.getTo().equals("H.P. Lovecraft") : "Wrong firstMessage to address";
        assert firstMessage.getContent().endsWith("Howard!") : "Wrong firstMessage content ending";

        MailMessage secondMessage = new MailMessage(
                "Jonathan Nolan",
                "Christopher Nolan",
                "Брат, почему все так хвалят только тебя, когда практически все сценарии написал я. Так не честно!"
        );

        MailMessage thirdMessage = new MailMessage(
                "Stephen Hawking",
                "Christopher Nolan",
                "Я так и не понял Интерстеллар."
        );

        List<MailMessage> messages = Arrays.asList(
                firstMessage, secondMessage, thirdMessage
        );

        for (MailMessage s : messages) {
            System.out.println(s.getFrom() + " " + s.getTo() + " " + s.getContent());
        }

// Создание почтового сервиса.
        MailService<String> mailService = new MailService<>();

// Обработка списка писем почтовым сервисом
        messages.stream().forEachOrdered(mailService);
/*
// Получение и проверка словаря "почтового ящика",
//   где по получателю можно получить список сообщений, которые были ему отправлены
        Map<String, List<String>> mailBox = mailService.getMailBox();

        assert mailBox.get("H.P. Lovecraft").equals(
                Arrays.asList(
                        "This \"The Shadow over Innsmouth\" story is real masterpiece, Howard!"
                )
        ): "wrong mailService mailbox content (1)";

        assert mailBox.get("Christopher Nolan").equals(
                Arrays.asList(
                        "Брат, почему все так хвалят только тебя, когда практически все сценарии написал я. Так не честно!",
                        "Я так и не понял Интерстеллар."
                )
        ): "wrong mailService mailbox content (2)";

        assert mailBox.get(randomTo).equals(Collections.<String>emptyList()): "wrong mailService mailbox content (3)";
```

**ВОПРОС** что я делаю неправильно и почему идет ошибка в этой строке :

```
messages.stream().forEachOrdered(mailService);

Required type: Consumer<? super MailMessage>
Provided: MailService <String>
```

Я уже совсем не знаю, что сделать дабы заставить эту строку работать ....

messages.stream().forEach(mailService::accept); - работает. Но эту строку надо оставить в неизменном виде ... 
т.е. .forEachOrdered(mailService)

Comment: Коллекция `List<MailMessage> messages` имеет тип `MailMessage` и значи в `forEach` тип будет `Consumer<MailMessage>`, а Вы ему передаете совсем другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
messages.stream().forEachOrdered(new Consumer<MailMessage>() {

    @Override
    public void accept(MailMessage mailMessage) {
        mailService.accept(mailMessage);
    }

});
```

И вот эту строку:

`public class MailMessage<T> implements Sendable{`

Следует заменить на эту:

`public class MailMessage<T> implements Sendable<T> {`

Comment: строку messages.stream().forEachOrdered(mailService); менять нельзя.

Comment: Если я ставлю Sendable<T>, то у меня сразу слетает тест :

getContent().endsWith("Howard!") 

т.к. контент становится T, а не стрингом ...

А если я в Sendable меняю getContent на стринг, то слетает следующее задание, когда getContent будет интом....

Comment: @Васька тогда так: `MailService<T>  implements Consumer<MailMessage> {`

Answer (score 0):

messages.stream().forEachOrdered(t -> mailService.accept(t)); - может так попробовать?

Comment: строку менять нельзя

Comment: @ Васька а что можно?

Comment: наверное MailService сделать консьюмером, ток я пока не понял как.

Comment: @ Васька  так он уже консьюмер, он его имплементит, а наследник всегда является суперклассом. но у консьюмера есть метод accept и его нужно вызвать, он определен из колробки в функциональном интерфейсе. мало того, консьюмер принимает в этот самый метод значение, которое тоже надо передать.